# How do I Voice reply to my Incoming Text SMS saying that “Message from this person”?

Tags: 8.1, sms, cortana, nokia-lumia-525

I recently updated my Lumia 525 with Windows 8.1. After that whenever I receive a text SMS from my friends, A lady voice saying that “Message from this person” and I want to reply to that SMS through my voice. Once I did that but I don’t remember how I did that. That message also says some other words but I was not able to understand the voice. Can any help me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you are hearing is because of the Speech setting available in the Windows Phone. 
You can turn on this feature from the **Settings>speech**. From here you can choose how the speech function should work for your phone. Also you can choose the type of voice (female/male) which you want to hear for the speech function.

**Speech setting for messaging:**

From my experience, when I receive a message, **I won't get an option to reply** to that particular message, What I'm getting is two options: "Read it or Ignore". 
If you are choosing 'Read it', the system will read the message for you, or if you are choosing 'ignore', the phone will simply ignore the message from reading.

But there is another way you can send a message to a particular contact. Just do a long press on the **search** button at the bottom right corner of the phone and say "Text XYZ" provided that XYZ must be a contact saved in your phone.

Also for the language/voice query you are mentioning, check from the Settings>speech and make sure that the Speech language selected is your preferred one.

NB: The speech setting is available for messaging, navigation and other third party apps as per the setting info.